Unable to extract user input using #userForm="ngForm"
I am creating a form in Angular which takes in user input. I am using #userForm="ngForm", which I believe is a directive which is able to read the input for the form sections.
I am printing out the input through:  {{ userForm.value | json}} 
however I am not receiving any output.
To use ngForm, I needed to import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`
and add FormsModule under imports. When I added these to my component module file (merchant.module.ts), it seemed to have no impact.
Once I added the imports under the app.module.ts, the program finally removed the ngForm error. From my understanding the import needs to be added within the same component, module's file but it is not able to tell it's been added.
I'm confused to how this should be set up.I'm wondering if I have set up my merchant component in an incorrect way and if there are any bugs I must fix within the app.module.ts file.
merchant.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MerchantComponent } from './merchant.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MerchantComponent
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MerchantComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule
  ]
})
export class MerchantModule { }

app.module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule, provideClientHydration } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// import { MerchantModule } from './merchant/merchant.module';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { MerchantComponent } from './merchant/merchant.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MerchantComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    // MerchantModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    provideClientHydration(),
    provideAnimationsAsync()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

files and folders of project

hey best to remove the API key from your question .
also , add the html that you used to create the form so we can review

#selector is used to reference an html element or angular component. However you cannot reference a directive like that since several directives can apply to the same element. Therefor we have the #directiveref="exportAsFromDirective" notation. Since you didn't share your html or error message, I can only guess that the ngForm directive wasn't applied in the first place

the issue is that you have declared MerchantComponent in both MerchantModule and AppModule. This results in conflicts.
You need to remove the MerchantComponent from the AppModule.
Tips for the Future

Generate a standalone component if the component should be standalone.
Generate the module before the component if you plan to group multiple components under a module:


ng generate module merchant

then:

ng generate component merchant/merchant --module=merchant


Thanks for pointing that out @AnwarMEQOR. I was able to remove MerchantComponent from the AppModule and I believe that helped me out.
